# jQuery: How to queue multiple AJAX asynchronous call

Tags: jquery

My application makes concurrent AJAX asynchronous calls to a server which only has 4 threads (Baracudda server, for example). I need to convert my concurrent AJAX async calls into sequential async calls. Is there any mechanism inside jQuery to do it? Please suggest.

**Code:**

```
function initiateAJAXRequest() {
    var promise = $.ajax({
        type: queue[0].options.type,
        url: queue[0].options.url,
        timeout: queue[0].options.timeout || 3000,
        cache: (!queue[0].options.cache) ? queue[0].options.cache : true,
        dataType: queue[0].options.dataType,
        data: queue[0].options.data         
    }).promise();


    promise.then(function(result) {
        console.log(queue[0]);  
        // I get an error in the line below: "xhr is undefined".
        queue[0].dfd.resolve(result);
        queue.splice(0, 1);
        if(queue.length > 0) {
            queue[0].isActiveRequest = true;
            initiateAJAXRequest();
        }
    });

    promise.fail(function(xhr, statusText, message) {
        queue[0].dfd.reject(arguments);
        queue.splice(0, 1);             
        if(queue.length > 0) {
            queue[0].isActiveRequest = true;                    
            initiateAJAXRequest();
        }
    });
}

function callAJAXAsync(options) {
    // Create deferred object. This will manage the promise chain who calls this method.
    var deferred = new $.Deferred();


    window.queue.push({dfd: deferred, options: options});
    window.queue = queue;

    if(!window.queue[0].isActiveRequest) {
        window.queue[0].isActiveRequest = true;             
        initiateAJAXRequest();
    }
    return deferred.promise();
};
```

This is the code I've written for the framework of my application. A single page can make multiple calls to callAJAXAsync() method. The problem is I get an error in the line commented inside initiateAJAXRequest().

**EDIT**
One thing that strikes me is, I am creating a new deferred object inside callAJAXAsync() method and resolving/rejecting it inside initiateAJAXRequest() method. Is that valid?

**SOLUTION**
This code works fine. The error was due to some other reason. Here is the fiddle that I created just in case... http://jsfiddle.net/LnaPt/

Comment: Can we see your current code?

Comment: you can try adding the setting `async: false`, not exactly what you want, but the other requests won't execute until the previous call returns

Comment: @MrGTgo, this is not what `OP` is asking, he needs `async` bt queued requests.

Comment: .... Your requests should already be sequential. One will happen, then when it is done, the next will until there is no next.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code works fine. The error was due to some other reason. You can check the fiddle posted in my query.

Answer (score 3):

If they truly need to be *sequential* then the response handler for each one can simply invoke the next one.  Something like this:

```
$.ajax({
    // options for the first call
}).done(function() {
    $.ajax({
        // options for the second call
    }).done(function () {
        // and so on
    });
});
```

Comment: I cannot have one ajax call dependent upon another. If one call fails so will be the other.

Comment: @AnupVasudeva: Maybe replace `.done()` with `.always()` in that case?

Comment: Can you have a look at my code and figure out what's the issue(I have commented above the line).

Answer (score -1):

After `url: queue[0].options.url,` you can use `async: false,`

`async: true,` is default behaviour for jQuery AJAX